# while studing flex boxes, i wrote the code creating some div tag , and gave it a border width and color, but it is now repeating the border

Tags: html, css, web, web-development-server

this is the html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>flex box</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="box1">box1</div>
            <div id="box2">box2</div>
            <div id="box3">box3</div>
            <div id="box4">box4</div>
            <div id="box5">box5</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>`
```

this is the css

```
 body{
        text-align:center;
    }
    #container{
        width:800px;
        height:200px;
        border-style:solid;
    }
    div{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        display:inline-block;
        border:2px;
        border-color:black;
        border-style:solid;
    } 
    #box1{
        background-color:red;
    }
    #box2{
        background-color:green;
    }
    #box3{
        background-color:blue;
    }
    #box4{
        background-color:yellow;
    }
    #box5{
        background-color:pink;
    }
```

I was expecting for it to give a result in which there would be a container div tag and inside that tag will be other div tags with different colour boxes having borders of 2px each, but it  is repating the boxes

this is a 50percent view of the page to include all of it.[code run result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24bkk.png)

Comment: Can you add more clarity as to what the issue is? Based on what you've provided, everything looks correct. Is it the boxes on the right? Have you provide the full html code?

Comment: Please make the code you have given into a runnable snippet and check that it shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I have run your code and it gives the result you describe as wanting - color divs inside a larger div.